# Python Random Module

Tags: python, random

Anyone have any good idea how to approach this. I'm trying to figure out if you can use the random module to create randomized outcomes. For instance you create a range of 1, 3 where those numbers equal different functions that are triggered when the number is chosen in the background. Here's the code I'm trying. I know it doesn't work but I'm still trying out different ideas but would love some help.

```
import random

random.choice('1 2')

if random.choice == "1":
    print("Hello")

if random.choice == "2":
    print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: Please read a bit more about functions in Python, and Python syntax in general.

Comment: `random.choice` is a function, so is never goong to be equal to a string...

Answer (score 3):

A few points:

- The line `random.choice('1 2')` makes a choice but doesn't do anything with it (such as bind it to a variable) - it's lost immediately and you'll never know what it was.
- Use `random.choice('12')` otherwise the space is one of the possible choices too.
- `random.choice` is just the name of the function: you're not calling it in your `if` statement, just comparing it to a string (it will be `False` and nothing will be printed).

The code might work better as follows:

```
import random

number = random.choice('12') # either '1' or '2' is chosen and bound 
                             # to the variable name "number"
if number == "1": 
    print("Hello")

if number == "2":
    print("Goodbye")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
import random
def function1():
   print("Hello")
def function2():
   print("Goodbye")
random_function = random.choice([function1, function2])
# call random function
random_function()
```